# Unity framework doesn't resolve OptionalDependency

Tags: c#, unity-container, prism

I'm building a program on Unity 5 and Prism 7. I want my program to be highly modular so I want it to behave correctly if some modules are unavailable.

For this I want to mark optional dependencies with `[OptionalDependency]` attribute and let a classes with them to decide themselves what to do if there's `null` passed in constructor.

But if I mark a dependency with this attribute, Unity doesn't resolve it and just pass `null` instead of dependency instance, despite the module is available as usual.

How do I make dependency as really ***nice to have***?

Or another option, how do I make Unity to ***not throw*** when dependency cannot be resolved, and just pass `null` instead and let the constructing classes decide what to do?

There's `App.xaml.cs` of my program:

```
public partial class App : PrismApplication
{
    protected override Window CreateShell()
    {
        InitializeModules();
        this.ShutdownMode = ShutdownMode.OnMainWindowClose;
        var shell = Container.Resolve<Shell>();
        this.MainWindow = shell;
        return shell;
    }

    protected override void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry) { }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creating catalog of Modules from .dlls in "Modules" folder
    /// </summary>
    protected override IModuleCatalog CreateModuleCatalog()
    {
        var catalog = new DirectoryModuleCatalog() { ModulePath = @"./Modules" };
        catalog.Initialize();
        // by the way, modules aren't getting recognized without
        // catalog.Initialize() or InitializeModules in CreateShell.
        // Should it be such as that? Seems to me like no..
        return catalog;
    }
}
```

Beside main question, I appreciate any suggestions on how to make my code better in the comments under the question, because I'm a noob in Prism+Unity. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This approach is not a good idea. Constructor injection means that the dependencies are required.  Also, I don't think the OptionalDependencyAttribute works in the ctor, but rather must be applied to a property.  Try making a property and applying the attribute to it.

All the code in the CreateShell method is not needed.  Just `return Container.Resolve<Shell>()` and that's it.

Also, the modules not loading is a bug which was fixed and is available in the latest Prism CI biuld on MyGet.

Comment: Why OptionalDependency attribute can be applied to parameter then? I don't see any other usage of marking paramethers with it beside a constructor parameters. And I moved to Prism 7.0.0.344-ci with MyGet and it still doesn't work without `InitializeModules();` in CreateShell, because it can't resolve one of the modules needed in my Shell view model constructor.

Comment: Also, I read that the implementation of IModule and the module functionality itself should be strictly in different classes so that the functionality doesn't depend on container used. But property injection means that my service must be IModule, or at least have a reference to it to get its property. What should I choose, and is there other way?

Comment: You'll have to ask the Unity team about the attribute behavior. If you change to a property did it wok?

The Shell is created first before any modules. You cannot request any module services in the Shell. If the Shell has dependencies, then they must be registered in the Shell project, not a module.

I don't understand your other question. Sounds like code smell to me (something wrong with the design).

Comment: Let me explain better. For each my module project I have at least 2 classes. 1 of them only implements IModule interface (Initialize), and constructor with dependencies needed. In its Initialize this class construct and register the second class, which implements the module functionality (like logging). I heard that this way the functionality doesn't get coupled with container, and if I change container, I need do remake only a class which implements IModule, leaving main functionality untouched. Property injection means these classes should be the same class, am I right?

Comment: No, property injection means that instead of asking for the dependency in the ctor, you ask for it as a property instead.

Comment: I mean, to access the property of IModule implementation class from class with main functionality, I must tie them up somehow. Or can I just safely pass property value into main class constructor in `Initialize`? I search for the way where optional dependency can be used right in the constructor. For example with logger, I don't want to miss some possible log entries before the logger gets passed into properties of classes which can use it.

Comment: Your design sounds broken. You don't access properties of IModule in another class. You simply ask for the dependency that the class needs. That's it.  If you have a service that both the Shell and IModule need, then register it in the Shell, and it can be injected anywhere in your app you need it.